# What's the difference between :new, :collection and :member routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I've read the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Resources.html#M000522), but I'm still not sure I understand everything.

Especially why there's a `:new` parameter. As far as I understand, it could be replaced with the `:collection` parameter.

**So what's the difference between those three types of routes?**

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The difference is the URL generated.
Let's guess three resources :

```
map.resources :users, :collection => { :rss => :get }
map.resources :users, :member => { :profile => :get }
map.resources :users, :new => { :draft => :get }
```

The first route will create :

```
/users/rss
```

With nothing between the controller name and the action name. We don't need any other parameter to get the user's list rss feed.

The second one will create the action "profile" as a member of the object. So we'll have :

```
/users/1/profile
```

The "1" is the user's `to_param`. We need a user's id to display a profile.

The third one will create the action "draft" as a member of the new action. So we'll have :

```
/users/new/draft
```

The "draft" action displays a draft of the user before accepting its creation.

So that's the difference between :collection, :member and :new. Every of them creates different routes, each one with their own purpose.

Comment: I realize this is an old post. I had some issues with actions routes between controllers using the `member` resource. I was able to solve my issue but I'm still unsure why `member` was causing the conflict. I tried searching this and couldn't find the information I was looking for. I believe you would know. Perhaps if you have a minute you can stop by my post and share some wisdom. Thanks!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21296591/rails-4-routing-and-sharing-actions-between-controllers-whats-the-proper-conv

Comment: what does the map.resources do?

Answer (score 9):

`:member` creates path with pattern `/:controller/:id/:your_method`

`:collection` creates path with the pattern `/:controller/:your_method`

`:new` creates path with the pattern `/:controller/:your_method/new` (please note that the last element of the path i.e. `new` is constant)

`New` differs from `Collection` mainly on the ideological layer. That's how REST gurus see the creation of the REST "subresource" within the bigger resource.

Comment: How would I get a path with pattern `/:controller/:your_method/:id`?

Answer (score 2):

Damiens explanation is mostly right except for the section about :new

Have a really good read of the ruby on rails routing guide at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html It explains routing from the inside out, and then back again. Section 3.11.3 (Adding New Routes) describes what :new does, and it is very different to :member and :collection.

Basically map.resources :photos, :new => { :upload => :post } will create /photos/upload using the POST HTTP verb.